# Change Page Template Based on Category

Tags: template-hierarchy

How can I display a post with a certain category in the page template instead of default category template.

For an example, I want to show all posts under category "Scott" with the page template ("page.php").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could also do what you want by filtering `template_include`. This is super-untested, but maybe this can get you headed in the right direction:

```
function wpse53871( $template ) {
    global $post;
    // check if is a Post and in the 'scott' category
    if( is_single( $post->ID ) && has_category( 'scott', $post ) ) {
        return get_template_part( 'page' );
    } else {
        return $template;
    }
}
add_filter( 'locate_template', 'wpse52871' );
```

Here's [another example](http://xazure.net/2011/06/tips-snippets/wordpress/changing-wordpress-template-with-template_include/) of the filter in use.

**Additional**

You can also add a filter to [single_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template)

`add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse53871' );`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Chris_O. You made me realized I forgot to add the filter to my snippet (which I will do now)! Take note, @daniel.tosaba. I didn't know about `single_template`. That's excellent. If you use that, I assume the function wouldn't need the `is_single()` check?

Comment: +1. Just a note: you might want to use `get_template_directory_uri()` - or, better yet, `locate_template()` - instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. Consider Child-Theme friendliness. :)

Comment: @chip bennett Good thought on `locate_template()`. I need to get in the habit of using that. Isn't "stylesheet_directory" the child theme friendly function?

Comment: "*Isn't "stylesheet_directory" the child theme friendly function?*" Only if the Child Theme includes the specified template file. `stylesheet_directory` refers to the *Child* Theme, and `template_directory` refers to the *Parent* Theme. So, it depends entirely on context/use-case. That's why I recommend using `locate_template()`. :) (Note: you could also use `get_template_part()`, which is basically a fancy wrapper for `locate_template()`.)

Answer (score 0):

There's two different types of content:
1. Pages http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages
2. Posts

Categories only apply to Posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

If you're using Pages, you want to create Parent and Child pages. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Organizing_Your_Pages

If you have a page and you want to list categories in it, you can add the list categories function to the page template http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Also, I wouldn't modify page.php unless you really want to, I'd create a custom page template http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates